# How to right-align and justify-align in Markdown?

Tags: markdown

Markdown text is always left-aligned. Is there a way to do right-align and justification in Markdown?

To be precise, I'm using Markdown in [Jupyter Notebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython#Project_Jupyter) (IPython).

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to change the alignment in Markdown (would make the compilers/renderes far more complex) - maybe there are some tools using extended syntax that can do it but right now I know of none (I think not even pandoc will do)

Comment: You can use some CSS to alter the alignment or the HTML output by Markdown in your browser. However, text alignment is outside the scope of Markdown itself.

Comment: If you will use html format you will be unable to use .md format inside that text. Best answer is in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49470805/how-to-make-markdown-text-align-justify For example: Hello, this is my `text`. {: style="text-align: justify"}

Comment: None of the solutions worked for me for bitbucket readme

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Aligning text in *pure* markdown is not possible. However, you can align the text using inline HTML tags.

```html
<div style="text-align: right"> your-text-here </div>
```

To justify, replace `right` with `justify` in the above.

Comment: It works, but it breaks links like `<div style="text-align: right"> [up](https://github.com/loretoparisi/CapsNet#CapsNet) </div>` will be not rendered as a link.

Comment: you can use `<a href="https://your-site.com">Your link</a>` tag inside ‍♂️

Comment: Inline HTML is often forbidden by Linters. I would avoid using inline html in markdown, I posted my suggestion as answer here to the question.

Comment: Unfortunately GitHub does not honor this in README.md files, but it is still better than other answers, where GitHub will not only fail to align text, but will also render the unrecognized markup verbatim on the page.

Comment: @MikeNakis GitHub strips the `style` attribute, but you can still use `align` and it will work: `<div align="right">your-text-here</div>`

Answer (score 58):

If you want to right-align in a form, you can try:

```
| Option | Description |
| ------:| -----------:|
| data   | path to data files to supply the data that will be passed into templates. |
| engine | engine to be used for processing templates. Handlebars is the default. |
| ext    | extension to be used for dest files. |
```

https://learn.getgrav.org/content/markdown#right-aligned-text

Answer (score 24):

If you want to use justify align in Jupyter Notebook use the following syntax:

```
<p style='text-align: justify;'> Your Text </p>
```

For right alignment:

```
<p style='text-align: right;'> Your Text </p>
```

Comment: Thanks for showing the `justify` option; the other posts talk only about right-align. This option seems to work well with the `div` tag too. Too bad I could only accept one answer :)

Comment: If you need to justify whole document like me, then add `p { text-align: justify; }` to the CSS. Additionally you can also add `ul { text-align: justify; }` for list elements.

Answer (score 10):

In a generic Markdown document, use:

`<style>body {text-align: right}</style>`

or

`<style>body {text-align: justify}</style>`

Does not seem to work with Jupyter though.

Comment: This answer is much better than the highest voted one. The solution suggested works with MD markup well. Everyone else keep suggesting the use of HTML syntax, which defeats the purpose of MD.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned here, markdown do not support right aligned text or blocks. But the HTML result does it, via Cascading Style Sheets ([CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_intro.asp)). HTML elements can be used inside markdown, so wrap your "text" in a `div` or `p` element and add the css stlyes as you want.

On my Jekyll Blog (which will render MD to HTML) I use a syntax which works in markdown as well. To "terminate" a block use two spaces at the end or two times new line.

Of course you can also add a css-class with `{: .right }` instead of css-sytle `{: style="text-align: right" }` directly. The css class "right" can be then styled via (external) css-sheet.

Text to right

```markdown
{: style="text-align: right" }
This text is on the right
```

Text as block

```markdown
{: style="text-align: justify" }
This text is a block
```

Comment: Maybe you need to clarify, for beginners, what a CSS class is and how to use it. And I think this only works in the Kramdown version of Markdown.

Comment: @Santiago, you are right is works only when markdown is generated as HTML

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40438921/6494296), I found out that when you are using MacDown on MacOs, you can `<div style="text-align: justify">` at the beginning of the document to justify all text and keep all `code` formating. Maybe it works on other editors too, for you to try ;)

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work for the entire document, just the paragraph. I use Typora as editor in Linux

Answer (score 2):

I used

```
<p align='right'>Farhan Khan</p>
```

and it worked for me on Google Colaboratory. Funnily enough it does not work anywhere else?

Comment: This is deprecated: https://html.com/attributes/div-align/   https://strictquirks.nl/standards/deprecated-attributes.html#p

Answer (score 1):

Specific to your usage of a Jupyter Notebook: the ability to specify table column alignment should return in a future release. (Current releases default to right-aligned everywhere.)

From [PR #4130](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/4130):

> Allow markdown tables to specify their alignment with the :--, :--:, --: syntax while still allowing --- to default to right alignment.
>
> This reverts a previous change (part of #2534) that stripped the alignment information from the rendered HTML coming out of the marked renderer. To be clear this does not change the right alignment default but does bring back support for overriding this alignment per column by using the gfm table alignment syntax.
>
> ...

Answer (score 0):

How to right-align text and hyperlinks are already answered and marked correct, but if you are going to reference something *within* Jupyter Notebook in your right-aligned text, you need to use a modified version of [Eradash's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54024656/4943342). The modification consists of **dropping the division closing bracket** `>` and **add a new blank line** before your linked text. So, if you like to link your headings to a Table of Contents, you may also want to have a right-aligned link to the 'Table of contents' in the same block for better notebook aesthetics and navigation.

Say you have a Table of Contents with links to your cell headings that looks like this in markdown:

```
<a id='Contents'></a>
### Table of Contents
* [Project description](#Project)
* [Load Data](#Load)
```

And later on, you have a cell containing the left-aligned header for some operations, and your right-aligned go-to link:

```
<a id='Load'></a>
#### Loading data
<div style="text-align: right"
     
[Go to table](#Contents)
```

This will give you a left-aligned Heading with a right aligned go-to-link. Your next cells follow without any modification of alignment:

[image]

(I'd be curious to know why this works this way, as this solutions seems more like a hack than anything else.)

PS: You *can* add the ending bracket `>` and even the end-tag `</div>` on a new line after your right-aligned linked text, but it will only add another line in the output together with a highlighted space, which of course defeats the aesthetic purpose:

[image]