# How to make markdown text align justify

Tags: markdown, kramdown

I use this

```
<p align="justify">
Some plain texts will be aligned justify
</p>
```

It is really awesome when I just have plain text. However, if I would like to justify something like this, it does not work correctly. The url and list will disappear.

````
[Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet](some-awesome-webpage), consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
- tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
- quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
- consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
```cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non```
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
````

My workplace for markdown support html and blablabla. I am new to this.

Any suggestions will be appreaciated!

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS to advanced styling, after each formatted text block:

```
{: style="text-align: justify"}
```

See screenshot below from http://kramdown.herokuapp.com/:

[image]

Comment: I tried similar one. but it will cancel the format of the text, like hyperlink, images and so on. Do you mean that I should directly copy and paste this pice of code to the css file or in the markdown file? Thank you!

Comment: This is an Attribute List (see examples [here](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#inline-attribute-lists) and [here](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/attr_list/)), which is a non-standard feature which is not available in most Markdown implementations and is usually off by default in the few that do support the feature.

Comment: And I just noticed that the question includes the [kramdown] tag, which is one of the implementations I pointed to above.

Comment: @ZayneNa Please add a break line between text blocks. You have to insert after each text block. Maybe you can just reference further as a `css class`. See my screenshot.