# Justify text in github's readme

Tags: html, github, readme

Is there any way to justify the text in the readme's file? I have tried with

```
<div dir="rtl">
    text...
</div>
```

and

```
<div dir="ltr">
    text...
</div>
```

and works, but the tag `justify` doesn't exist.. Other solution that I have checked is via this question

[How to right-align and justify-align in Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35077507/how-to-right-align-and-justify-align-in-markdown)

```
<div style="text-align: justify">
    text
</div>
```

but neither works... Is there any way to perform it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to right-align and justify-align in Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35077507/how-to-right-align-and-justify-align-in-markdown)

Comment: Hi @dejdej No... with `<div style="text-align: justify">` neither works... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I lined up some text today and what worked was this:

`<div align="justify"> your text </div>`

Answer (score 5):

you can use the following for such:

```
<p align="justify"> Your Text </p>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).