# Mixing left and right justification in Markdown

Tags: markdown

I am trying to get suitable text alignment in a markdown file. I have been using HTML to justify text. The problem occurs when I want the text on one side to be left-justified and on the other side right-justified with no new line in between.

`<div style="text-align: right"> Your Text Here </div>`

For example:

`Text Here .............................................................Text Here (Omitting the periods)`

I have also tried

```
<p style="text-align: right; margin: 0;">This text is aligned to the right.</p><p style="text-align: left; margin: 0;">This text is aligned to the left.</p>
```

However, this still skews the text making it look like the following.

```
Text Here
..................................................Text Here
```

Comment: have you tried this ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40438921/1461862

Comment: Yeah actually I have read that

Comment: you have read it, but what happen when you try it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to right-align and justify-align in Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35077507/how-to-right-align-and-justify-align-in-markdown)

Comment: You gave the answer too which is awesome I like how you used the embedded HTML

Comment: Sadly no this article does not work I get a new line in between.

Comment: It feels like you need to update your question with that part, since is not very clear just with the comments

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252861/discussion-between-david-wisniewski-and-mauricio-gracia-gutierrez).

Comment: for now i have nothing else to say, sorry